# Nested XML to joined MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, nested

I have some data with nested fields that I would like to import into MySQL. A lot of files, potentially, so any repeatable scripting language is appreciated. It seems like this should be easier than I am making it, but I can't find a good answer.

I believe the cleanest way would be with joined tables, though it would be nice to have one element ALSO present in the parent table, say if it had the kind code "A1" in the sample below.

A similar query was answered here [Parsing nested xml into denormalized table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418517/parsing-nested-xml-into-denormalized-table) except that wasn't MySQL and that data came with a unique identifier. One of the challenges of my data is that there is no unique identifier in the data to create the primary key for joining tables.

Sample data below. Here, the doc-id and assignor tags would have to be separate tables and joined. The data has a DTD that I'm not including for what it's worth. Any input is much appreciated!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assignment>
    <assignment-record>
        <reel-no>28879</reel-no>
        <frame-no>97</frame-no>
        <last-update-date><date>20120903</date></last-update-date>
        <recorded-date><date>20120830</date></recorded-date>
        <page-count>4</page-count>
        <correspondent>
            <name>LEE, HONG, DEGERMAN, KANG &amp; WAIMEY</name>
            <address-1>660 S. FIGUEROA ST., 23RD FL.</address-1>
            <address-2>LOS ANGELES, CA 90017</address-2>
        </correspondent>
        <conveyance-text>ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).</conveyance-text>
    </assignment-record>
    <assignors>
        <assignor>
            <name>WOO, SUNGHO</name>
            <execution-date><date>20120806</date></execution-date>
        </assignor>
            <assignor>
                <name>CHOI, JAEYOUNG</name>
                <execution-date><date>20120806</date></execution-date>
        </assignor>
    </assignors>
    <docproperties>
        <property>
            <document-id>
                <country>US</country>
                <doc-number>13277056</doc-number>
                <kind>X0</kind>
                <date>20111019</date>
            </document-id>
            <document-id>
                <country>US</country>
                <doc-number>20120213136</doc-number>
                <kind>A1</kind>
                <date>20120823</date>
            </document-id>
            <title lang="en">SYSTEMS AND METHODS FOR CONTROLLING SENSOR DEVICES IN MOBILE DEVICES</title>
     </property>
    </docproperties>
</assignment>
</xml>
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html)?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That looks to get 90% there, except I don't have a uniqueid field in the parent that I can automatically drop into the children (that would be nice). I could potentially pick some fields that might be unique in combination, but I can't be assured of that, I don't think.

Comment: Also, I have a couple fields where the date is buried in a double field - <execution-date><date>20120806</date></execution-date> and I don't know that LOAD XML will handle that - though I haven't tested that particular aspect.

Comment: Confirming the XML Load did not work with the nested date tags since it only looked for the top date. I wound up writing a python script from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Since this three-year old unanswered question was recently bumped up by another user, I went ahead and answered it on behalf of the community as the original OP is no longer active.

For future readers, anytime you need to flatten nested XML files for flatfile import such as database tables consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the transformation language used to manipulate XML files. Practically all general purpose languages has some library for XSLT 1.0 processing including Python, PHP, Perl, Java, C#, VB, and others.

As OP mentioned Python, below examples uses the third-party [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) module to flatten the XML file. And to generate a unique id to relate the `<assignor>` and `<document-id>` data, an XPath in XSLT script is run using `ancestor` to retrieve the the *reel-no* value from `<assignment-record>` which both nodes share as a sibling. This is similar to the TSQL solution in posted link.

**XSLT** Scripts *(save as .xsl to be referenced in Python)*

Assignor Transformation

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/assignment">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::assignor"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="assignor">
    <xsl:copy>
      <assign_id>
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::assignment/assignment-record/reel-no"/>
      </assign_id>
      <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="execution-date/date"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Document-id Transformation

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/assignment">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::document-id"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="document-id">
    <xsl:copy>
      <assign_id>
          <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::assignment/assignment-record/reel-no"/>
      </assign_id>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script *(transforms source into two files)*

```py
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('Assignment.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('Assignor_XSLT_Script.xsl')

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)    

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Assignor.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(newdom)
xmlfile.close()    

xslt = ET.parse('Document-Id_XSLT_Script.xsl')    
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Document-Id.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(newdom)
xmlfile.close()
```

**XML** Outputs *(can now use MySQL's LOAD XML effectively)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assignment>
  <assignor>
    <assign_id>28879</assign_id>
    <name>WOO, SUNGHO</name>
    <date>20120806</date>
  </assignor>
  <assignor>
    <assign_id>28879</assign_id>
    <name>CHOI, JAEYOUNG</name>
    <date>20120806</date>
  </assignor>
</assignment>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assignment>
  <document-id>
    <assign_id>28879</assign_id>
    <country>US</country>
    <doc-number>13277056</doc-number>
    <kind>X0</kind>
    <date>20111019</date>
  </document-id>
  <document-id>
    <assign_id>28879</assign_id>
    <country>US</country>
    <doc-number>20120213136</doc-number>
    <kind>A1</kind>
    <date>20120823</date>
  </document-id>
</assignment>
```

Comment: Thank you - this looks great. I solved it in a similar, though far less elegant way by parsing the xml. It's not that I'm no longer active - I barely was to begin with :)

Comment: Wow! I am a believer. There are many SO users that ask 1 - 2 questions and then are gone forever. Good to know you still check in! Please ask more tech questions. Happy coding!